# Connect to Private RDS with local GUI via SSM

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-ssm

I have followed AWS's documentation on how to open a remote port forwarding session from my EC2 to RDS. I want to be able to securely access my DB on my local GUI.

My current setup consists of an EC2 hosting my app, a private RDS PSQL instance. I have my SG rules to allow only the EC2 to talk to the RDS instance directly. However I'm not sure if I'm setting up the right inbound rules for port forwarding. These are my inbound rules for the EC2. I know opening up a 5432 port is probably wrong but just wanteed to see if it did anything and it didn't.

[image]

For connecting via SSM I'm doing this:

```
aws ssm start-session \
  --target <MY_EC2_INSTANCE_ID>\
  --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
  --parameters '{"host":["<MY_RDS_URL>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"],"portNumber":[ \
     "5432"], "localPortNumber":["5432"]}'
```

This however gets stuck on

```
Starting session with SessionId: some-session-id
```

So I'm actually able to start a session with the EC2, But never actually says port forwarding has started (as I have seen in some examples). I have tried almost everything. I'd appreciate any help i can get.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you don't have local postgres service running on your machine. That would collide with port you are trying to map.